# mkl: invalid value error exporing sparse matrix

Tags: fortran, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

The following program uses Intel MKL and creates a sparse matrix from the coordinate represenation, then the matrix is exported to the [CSR format](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/appendix-a-linear-solvers-basics/sparse-matrix-storage-formats/sparse-blas-csr-matrix-storage-format.html#sparse-blas-csr-matrix-storage-format_CSR3).

```
  include 'mkl_spblas.f90'
program test

  use iso_c_binding
  use mkl_spblas
  implicit none

  complex(kind=kind(0.d0)) :: values(4)
  integer :: columns(4)
  integer :: rows(4)

  TYPE(C_PTR) :: rows_start_csr, rows_end_csr, col_index_csr, values_csr
  integer(C_INT) :: indexing_csr, nrows_csr, ncol_csr
  type(SPARSE_MATRIX_T) :: handle
  integer :: stat

  ! Matrix
  !
  ! | 0 1 0 0 |
  ! | 1 0 0 0 |
  ! | 0 0 1 0 |
  ! | 0 0 0 1 |
  values(1) = 1
  rows(1) = 1
  columns(1) = 2

  values(2) = 1
  rows(2) = 2
  columns(2) = 1

  values(3) = 1
  rows(3) = 3
  columns(3) = 3

  values(4) = 1
  rows(4) = 4
  columns(4) = 4

  stat = mkl_sparse_z_create_coo(handle, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, 4, 4, 4, rows, columns, values)
  write (*,*) 'stat after create = ', stat
  stat = mkl_sparse_z_export_csr(handle, indexing_csr, nrows_csr, ncol_csr, rows_start_csr, rows_end_csr, col_index_csr, values_csr)
  write (*,*) 'stat after export = ', stat, '  SPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE = ', SPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE
  
end program test
```

The output of the program is:

```
 stat after create =            0
 stat after export =            3   SPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE =            3
```

While after the matrix creation the status is OK, surprisingly, the status after exporting it corresponds to `SPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE`.

How can this possibly happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your COO format to CSR beforehand.

```pascal
include 'mkl_spblas.f90'
program test

  use iso_c_binding
  use mkl_spblas
  implicit none

  complex(kind=kind(0.d0)) :: values(4)
  integer                  :: columns(4)
  integer                  :: rows(4)

  TYPE(C_PTR)           :: rows_start_csr, rows_end_csr, col_index_csr, values_csr
  integer(C_INT)        :: indexing_csr, nrows_csr, ncol_csr
  type(SPARSE_MATRIX_T) :: coo, csr   ! ===== NEW
  integer               :: stat

  ! Matrix
  !
  ! | 0 1 0 0 |
  ! | 1 0 0 0 |
  ! | 0 0 1 0 |
  ! | 0 0 0 1 |
  values(1) = 1
  rows(1) = 1
  columns(1) = 2

  values(2) = 1
  rows(2) = 2
  columns(2) = 1

  values(3) = 1
  rows(3) = 3
  columns(3) = 3

  values(4) = 1
  rows(4) = 4
  columns(4) = 4

  stat = mkl_sparse_z_create_coo(coo, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, 4, 4, 4, rows, columns, values)
  write (*,*) 'stat after create = ', stat

  ! ===== NEW ===== ->
  stat = mkl_sparse_convert_csr(coo, SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, csr)
  write (*,*) 'stat after convert = ', stat
  ! ===== NEW ===== <-

  stat = mkl_sparse_z_export_csr(csr, indexing_csr, nrows_csr, ncol_csr, rows_start_csr, rows_end_csr, col_index_csr, values_csr)
  write (*,*) 'stat after export = ', stat, '  SPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE = ', SPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE

end program
```

Comment: On my machine I get " stat after convert =            2", that would be ```SPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED```

Comment: strange mine runs smoothly. `stat after convert = 0` ...

Comment: ok, turns out I had to add ```-fdefault-integer-8``` to the command line and declare ```nrows_csr, ncol_csr``` as integer. not sure why this is needed

Comment: It depends on which mkl you link to. if you use the ilp64 mkl then you need 64bit integers.